# Rails 6 Webpacker: Attempting to install jQuery and JS library

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

## Rails 6, Webpacker and [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)

Quick demo app: https://github.com/ratahtatah/flickedyflack

### Try 1: Pure jQuery

```
TypeError: $(...).flickity is not a function
```

#### app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("jquery")

require("flickity")
import "flickity/dist/flickity.min.css";

$(".main-carousel").flickity({
  contain: true
});
```

#### config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    flickity: 'flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

### Try 2: jQuery w/ jQueryBridget (Feifei Xiong)

```
No errors, but also no initialization
```

#### app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var jQueryBridget = require('jquery-bridget');
var Flickity = require('flickity');

jQueryBridget('flickity', Flickity, $);

$(".main-carousel").flickity({
  contain: true
});
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "flicketyflack",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "flickity": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-bridget": "^2.0.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `package.json`

Comment: @FeifeiXiong all done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use jquery-bridget to initialize Flickity as a jQuery plugin.

```
yarn add jquery-bridget
```

Then in application.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var jQueryBridget = require('jquery-bridget');
var Flickity = require('flickity');

jQueryBridget( 'flickity', Flickity, $ );

# If your are using turbolinks
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(".main-carousel").flickity({
    contain: true
  });
});
```

If you are not using turbolinks, try following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main-carousel").flickity({
    contain: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm not getting any errors, but it's also not initializing. Please wait as I push a demo app to GitHub!

Comment: Added your example to the question, I hope that's okay. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @MarkBoulder, what you mean not initializing? Are there any errors? I noticed that you commented `import "flickity/dist/flickity.min.css"`, can you add CSS back and check if it works?

Comment: Hi @MarkBoulder, I noticed you commented `require("turbolinks").start()`, could you add it back, and add the code what I updated in my answer.

Comment: Hi @MarkBoulder, I updated my answer for not using turbolinks.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Mind if I ask though: 1) How come all the sides in our example appear in the same slide? Is there some extra CSS we must apply that's not in the docs?, 2) How come the author doesn't mention Bridget in his docs? Shouldn't it be built in? I noticed there are some references in the code.

Comment: Q1 What's the meaning of the same slide?
Q2 I am not very sure about this. It probably the order. Could you try `require("jquery")`  then `require("flickity")`, and check if it works without jquery-bridget.

Comment: Sorry, wrong order, I was thinking `require("flickity")` then `require("jquery")` and check if it works without jquery-bridget

Comment: You know what, I've decided to build my own carousel from the ground up. I need a Tinder-like carousel anyway for which there are tons of tutorials out there, plus I get the feeling it would take ages to patch Flickery for this. Also Flickery is enormous.

Comment: Wow, good luck, by the way, if you are using bootstrap, it is easy to use bootstrap carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your application.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Add it before `$(".main-carousel").flickity...`